# Custom UITableViewCell Lables shift position once selected with Checkmark

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using table view with custome `UITableViewCell`. When user select row , using `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` property, label position does not remain same...as shown below:

[image]

can be seen from above image, row1 and row2 labels shifted position. 
how can i keep cell without shift towards left....

Comment: How do you customer your `UITableViewCell` to show that much text?

Comment: @user2813740 : I believe you are making use of tableView edit mode, dont use it instead have an imageView at the end of each cell hide it when not selected when need to be shown display it :) Cell will not shift to left :)

Comment: i have custome UITableViewCell(ConTableViewCell), and i am suing like below:                      cell = [[[ConTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier cellType:strCellType]autorelease];  in ConTableViewCell, i have added 4 labels....

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are giving trailing space to the end labels. If yes remove the trailing space. Also give high priority to the leading space.

Comment: no i am not even frame for each label is same without checkmark or with checkmark.